# Customize position of jQRangeSlider labels

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I'm using jQRangeSlider plugin for creating date slider. But I can't change label positions to be left/right alligned. It is centeres dy default.
Does any way exist to custom its position? Or may someone offer a better decision for this block?
[image]
The site with issue is here: http://g1un.ru/navystavke/

Answer (score 0):

The easier way would be not to move the position of the label, but the position of the down arrow, because the position of the label is dynamically calculated in the js.

Now it is:

```
.calendar__slider .ui-rangeSlider-leftLabel .ui-rangeSlider-label-inner {
    left: 21px;
}
```

You can update it to:

```
.calendar__slider .ui-rangeSlider-leftLabel .ui-rangeSlider-label-inner {
    left: 35px;
}
```

for the left label.

And for the right label from:

```
.calendar__slider .ui-rangeSlider-rightLabel .ui-rangeSlider-label-inner {
    right: 12px;
}
```

to

```
.calendar__slider .ui-rangeSlider-rightLabel .ui-rangeSlider-label-inner {
    right: 26px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can't change the design. Moreover this decision doesn't resolve the problem of overflowing in mobile version.

Comment: This would change only the custom position of the down arrow, it will not affect the design.

Comment: It doesn't resolve the overflow problem: [link](https://monosnap.com/file/6CHAX5eX9CIEyb9e8EkO0SbFoCE8EK)
And it is still out of design, which must be: [link](http://take.ms/Fun3x)

Comment: Is this not overflowed, but sticked to the left and right border?